# Bios boot option what’s this?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, reinstall

I’m trying to boot from usb in my bios.  I’ve come across different options one being
[UEFI: KingstonDataT…]
What is it used for?  I’m think of deleting it running mint and trying to reinstall using usb though can’t find a usb setting in. Bios. Thank you

Comment: The option you mentioned is exactly the one you should choose to boot your USB media. It may have another without the "UEFI:" part. DON'T use that one because it'll boot in Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode, that mode that you shouldn't use for modern hardware and the only reason it shows up is because a) your media can boot in both modes and b) you have enabled Legacy/CSM in UEFI (BIOS isn't used since 2012).

Comment: What brand is your USB stick? Kingston is a common brand of USB storage devices, and if you're using a Kingston-brand stick, then that's probably the right device. Usually, the brand or name of the stick is what shows up in the bootable device list, but you'll need to confirm that is the right device.